# Splitting csv file of multiple objects over time by time-point

Tags: python, excel, csv, split, divide

Here I have an example file of multiple objects each measured at the same time-points (also ND.T represents each unique time point). I would like to split this file into separate files (using a python script) containing all objects unique to each time-point still containing the header.

Original file:

```
ID  ND.T    Time [s]    Position X [%s] Position Y [%s] Speed [%s]  Area [%s]   Width [%s]  MeanIntensity
1   1        3.87         417.57          11.46          0.06        339.48       14.1          245.65
1   2        8.72         417.37          11.68          0.04        342.61       14.15         239.34
1   3        13.39        417.57          11.66          0.04        344.17       14.3          239.48
2   1        3.87         439.01           6.59          0.02        342.61       11.66         204.47
2   2        8.72         438.97           6.65          0.007       342.61       10.7          197.96
2   3        13.39        438.94           6.66          0.03        345.74       11.03         214.74
```

Time_3.87.csv

```
ID  ND.T    Time [s]    Position X [%s] Position Y [%s] Speed [%s]  Area [%s]   Width [%s]  MeanIntensity
1   1        3.87         417.57          11.46          0.06        339.48       14.1          245.65
2   1        3.87         439.01           6.59          0.02        342.61       11.66         204.47
```

Time_8.72.csv

```
ID  ND.T    Time [s]    Position X [%s] Position Y [%s] Speed [%s]  Area [%s]   Width [%s]  MeanIntensity
1   2        8.72         417.37          11.68          0.04        342.61       14.15         239.34
2   2        8.72         438.97           6.65          0.007       342.61       10.7          197.96
```

Time_13.39.csv

```
ID  ND.T    Time [s]    Position X [%s] Position Y [%s] Speed [%s]  Area [%s]   Width [%s]  MeanIntensity
1   3        13.39        417.57          11.66          0.04        344.17       14.3          239.48
2   3        13.39        438.94           6.66          0.03        345.74       11.03         214.74
```

Example 2:

```
ID  ND.T    Time [s]    Position X [%s] Position Y [%s] Speed [%s]  Area [%s]   Width [%s]  MeanIntensity
1   1   3.87    417.57  11.46   0.06    339.48  14.1    245.65
1   2   8.72    417.37  11.68   0.04    342.61  14.15   239.34
1   3   13.39   417.57  11.66   0.04    344.17  14.3    239.48
1   4   18.1    417.73  11.71   0.04    337.92  14.14   225.17
1   5   22.81   417.83  11.89   0.03    344.17  14.64   233.3
1   6   27.48   417.69  11.83   0.02    345.74  14.23   238
1   7   32.16   417.65  11.94   0.03    345.74  14.71   230.75
2   1   3.87    439.01  6.59    0.02    342.61  11.66   204.47
2   2   8.72    438.97  6.65    0.007   342.61  10.7    197.96
2   3   13.39   438.94  6.66    0.03    345.74  11.03   214.74
2   4   18.1    438.9   6.53    0.04    342.61  10.46   202.9
2   5   22.81   438.97  6.7 0.02    342.61  10.3    194.32
2   6   27.48   438.89  6.71    0.006   350.43  11  219.41
2   7   32.16   438.87  6.74    0.05    348.87  10.36   219.58
```

Comment: Are you using `pandas` for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your_file)
df.groupby('Time [s]').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(str(x.name) + '.csv'))
```

The above will load your csv using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) and then group on the Time [s] column and use this to name the file

You can see that the df is grouped on the Time [s]:

```
In [108]:
df.groupby('Time [s]').apply(lambda x: print(x))
   ID  ND.T  Time [s]  Position X [%s]  Position Y [%s]  Speed [%s]  \
0   1     1      3.87           417.57            11.46        0.06   
3   2     1      3.87           439.01             6.59        0.02   

   Area [%s]  Width [%s]  MeanIntensity  
0     339.48       14.10         245.65  
3     342.61       11.66         204.47  
   ID  ND.T  Time [s]  Position X [%s]  Position Y [%s]  Speed [%s]  \
0   1     1      3.87           417.57            11.46        0.06   
3   2     1      3.87           439.01             6.59        0.02   

   Area [%s]  Width [%s]  MeanIntensity  
0     339.48       14.10         245.65  
3     342.61       11.66         204.47  
   ID  ND.T  Time [s]  Position X [%s]  Position Y [%s]  Speed [%s]  \
1   1     2      8.72           417.37            11.68       0.040   
4   2     2      8.72           438.97             6.65       0.007   

   Area [%s]  Width [%s]  MeanIntensity  
1     342.61       14.15         239.34  
4     342.61       10.70         197.96  
   ID  ND.T  Time [s]  Position X [%s]  Position Y [%s]  Speed [%s]  \
2   1     3     13.39           417.57            11.66        0.04   
5   2     3     13.39           438.94             6.66        0.03   

   Area [%s]  Width [%s]  MeanIntensity  
2     344.17       14.30         239.48  
5     345.74       11.03         214.74  

Out[108]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Here [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) will group on 'Time [s]' column, we then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) to apply a `lambda` where we call the method `to_csv` on each grouping, we can access the group name using `name` attribute which is of `dtype` `int` so we cast to `str` and construct our csv name:

```
In [109]:
df.groupby('Time [s]').apply(lambda x: print(str(x.name) + '.csv'))

3.87.csv
8.72.csv
13.39.csv
Out[109]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: That is a very nice solution.  I would have done this in several lines, but good work on invoking lambda!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response. I was able to install pandas and tested to make sure it works. Now when I am trying to run the script I get this error: NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: Sorry you need to add the import at beginning: `import pandas as pd` I'll update my answer

Comment: Okay that's what I figured. So I have added another test file to the post that I am trying to use this script on and keep getting this error: pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 526, saw 2

Comment: I assumed your csv was comma separated, if not then you need to edit your question with the first few raw lines in order for me to suggest how to load it

Comment: Okay, I just edited the file to be comma separated and it works perfectly. Thanks for all your help - I'm gonna learn more about lambda and pandas to help me in the future.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Comment: One more thing, I am noticing is that there is an extra column now to the left of the ID column. What does that column represent and how could I optimize the script to output files without it?

Comment: That's an index column, if you don't want it pass index=False to to_csv